# Clause and phrases analysis

Tags: sentence-construction

> It shames us as a nation that a freedom fighter has to scrape a living
> singing in the streets.

What type of clause is *"that a freedom fighter has to scrape a living singing in the streets"* in this sentence?

- A. a noun clause
- B. an adjective
- C. an adverb

Please, explain

Comment: It's none of those. This is an extraposition  construction, where the _that_ clause is a **declarative content clause** functioning as 'extraposed' subject.

Comment: It is *effectively* a noun phrase - shortened / resequenced from ***"it" = the fact** [that something is the case]*.

Comment: The same example was asked here: [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/556549/problem-with-that-clause/556552#5565520)

Answer (score 1):

It is a noun clause. You can restate the sentence as

> That a freedom fighter has to scrape a living singing in the streets shames us as a nation

English, however, finds it awkward to make a subordinate clause the subject of a sentence. The “it” in your sentence is formally the subject of the sentence but carries no meaning on its own. The referent of the pronoun “it,” which does carry the meaning, is a subordinate clause placed at the end of the independent clause. This is a very common construction in English.

Answer (score 0):

> *It shames us as a nation* [*that a freedom fighter has to scrape a living*
> *singing in the streets*].

That bracketed element is a declarative content clause.

This is an extraposition construction with the dummy pronoun "it" as subject and the content clause as extraposed subject.

The basic (non-extraposed) version would be:

*That a freedom fighter has to scrape a living singing in the streets shames us as a nation.*

The extraposed version can be regarded as the default, mainly because it is more common. This is because subordinate clauses tend to be 'heavier' (longer and structurally more complex) and there is a general preference for placing heavier material at the end of the matrix clause.

Incidentally, I strongly recommend dropping the term 'noun clause'. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Comment: Will whoever downvoted my answer please state why.